# change the Theme dynamically

Tags: page-template, theme-options, child-theme, theme-customizer

Is there some way to change the page template dynamically using just a url I wanna use it in a demo theme, so for example when the user enters a particular URL ending with for example

?custom_page_template

it changes the template on the fly?

Could this technique be used to change the theme (or maybe a child theme) on the fly just for demo purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter `pre_option_stylesheet`. Sample code, not tested:

```
add_filter( 'pre_option_stylesheet', 'wpse_100854_switch_stylesheet' );

function wpse_100854_switch_stylesheet( $false )
{
    if ( empty ( $_GET['theme'] )
        return $false;

    $themes = wp_get_themes( array( 'allowed' => true ) );

    if ( isset ( $themes[ $_GET['theme'] ] ) )
        return $_GET['theme'];

    return $false;
}
```

The URL should look like `example.com/?theme=theme_directory_slug`.

To change just the *template* for a specific page, hook into `template_include`:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'wpse_100854_switch_template' );

function wpse_100854_switch_template( $template )
{
    if ( empty ( $_GET['template'] )
            return $false;

    // do not allow to break out of the directory
    $new  = ltrim( $_GET['template'], '.' ); 
    $path = get_template_directory() . "/templates/$new.php";

    if ( file_exists( $path ) )
        return $path;

    return $template;
}
```

Now add a directory `templates` to your theme. When someone requests `example.com/?template=blue` and the template `blue.php` exists in the special directory, it will be used.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the function, I have found these links, could be useful:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/pre_option_(option_name)

http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/switch_theme-vs-theme-switching

Comment: Now, I have used this function, How can I use it?
-
I mean now what is the URL I am after?

Comment: @CapitalH.ir See my update.

Comment: Why do you use 'pre_option_stylesheet' instead of 'pre_option_template'? Also, could you not use the action 'template_redirect'?

Comment: @MagentaCuda This filter runs as early as possible. `template_redirect` is way too late.

Comment: Does "template_redirect is way too late" mean that it will not work or just that 'pre_option_stylesheet' is more efficient?

Comment: @MagentaCuda `template_redirects` runs after the original theme’s `functions.php` has been loaded.

Comment: Does that mean it will not work?

Comment: @MagentaCuda Yes, of course.

Comment: Ah, I understand - it is a theme redirect and pre_option_stylesheet is returning a theme not a stylesheet.

Comment: @toscho Thanks very much, I don't have enough reputation to up vote your answer.

One more question. I think this method works for themes. How could we change the wordpress custom page templates on the fly?

Is it possible at all?

Comment: @CapitalH.ir See my update; I have added a second filter for templates.

Comment: @toscho thanks again, One more question. how to reset it back to normal? does a normal refresh reset it? if so is there some way to get it stick to the new template until a reset switch is triggered? or does it involve caching and cookies and makes it really complicated? I learning from you, and I'm learning the good parts of PHP and WP

Comment: @CapitalH.ir The alternative theme is used with the query parameter only. To make it stick, use cookies. But that would require much more code … and I guess there are already some plugins doing that.